# Best Method to Push Data from Scrapy to .Net Application

Tags: c#, .net, scrapy, screen-scraping, asp.net-core-signalr

Best Method/Idea to push scraped data from Scrapy crawlers to .Net Application

Setup:

1. Debian server runs a scrapy server
2. Windows server run a .Net Core application server

I am thinking about adding a RESTful API to my .Net Core Service and push item data there from Scrapy on every crawler "finished" event.

Basically I want to have kind of "push-notifications" from Scrapy server to my .Net app when new data item is scraped.

What is the best place to put that call to an external API in scrapy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple options here. Pushing data is indeed the easiest solution, though make sure to authorize the requests you make to your API. You can use the [item_scraped signal](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/signals.html#item-scraped) to invoke your requests for every scraped item. Keep in mind that in case there are hundreds of scraped items, it might put a lot of stress on your API which is something you should avoid. You can wait until the scraper has finished and then invoke your API with a single request. Some alternative solutions:

- Put scraped items in your database and poll the database for new items in the other application
- Use a messaging queue like RabbitMQ, AWS SQS or Kafka

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion. How can I push after scraper has finished? Is this on scrapy.signals.spider_closed signal?

Comment: here is an example: https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/3104
Note that you have multiple options, you could just as well use a pipeline. I would suggest to explore the scrapy API and to do some searches yourself, you will quickly find a way to achieve what you want.